# dual boot ubuntu 14.04 wont recognize USB

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, usb

I'm trying to dual boot Ubuntu 14.04 alongside Windows 10 (which was previously upgraded from Windows 7 so it's running on legacy BIOS). I've done everything http://www.everydaylinuxuser.com/2015/11/how-to-install-ubuntu-linux-alongside_8.html said to do up to "Boot into Ubuntu Live Environment." When I reboot, the computer is not reading the USB. Booting into Ubuntu is not an option. Can someone please help me?

Comment: By default, the USB stick won't be first in the boot priority. You need to change that in your BIOS settings, or go into the BIOS boot menu and select it there.

Comment: @Zacharee1 how do I change my BIOS settings or go into the BIOS boot menu? Is the BIOS boot menu the blue

Comment: You should be pressing a key to boot into the BIOS boot menu. That key depends on your computer.

Comment: I have a Lenovo Thinkpad. Let me try to reboot to get to BIOS menu...

Comment: Ok, I think I'm in the BIOS menu... It's a gray screen with black and blue type. I got to the Startup page, but boot from USB does not seem to be an option. What should I do?

Comment: I would recommend remaking the USB media, this time using [Rufus](http://rufus.akeo.ie)

Comment: I'll put it as an answer then :)

Answer (score 1):

(From our discussions in the comments)

The program you used to burn Ubuntu to the USB stick (I have nevereven heard of Win32 Disk Imager before now) was causing problems. A much better alternative to creating bootable USB sticks is [Rufus](http://rufus.akeo.ie). Use that to reburn the USB stick and you will be able to boot into the installation.

If you need to create bootable USBs in Ubuntu, use [UNetbootin](https://unetbootin.github.io/). If you prefer open-source software, even on Windows, use that as well. It isn't quite as stable as Rufus, nor does it have the best success rate. However, it's cross-platform and open-source.

Answer (score 0):

Before your computer loads any OS, when you see your manufacturers loading screen, there will be a prompt when will allow you to enter your BIOS settings. Hit the key it says, Esc for me, and then from the boot menu select your USB. This should load up Ubuntu instead of Windows. You need to do this because, by default, your computer is setup to load Windows first before anything else.

Answer (score 0):

As soon as the system boots it will display on the screen press "something on keyboard" to change settings. It may say to enter bios. On some systems it is the ESC key or F12 or DEL. You have to look for the message right after you turn it on. Do not cold boot "restart from within the operating system". Shut the machine down so it is off and use the power button to turn it on.

Once in the bios you may have to search for your boot preferences, boot order or something like that. It may be in advanced settings. You will have to select whatever drive or usb stick you want to boot from.

My system is set to boot usb stick if none exist boot cdrom if none exist boot hard drive.